# How to pass StateObject to a UIKit Sheet with UIKit Navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

My goal is to pass `StateObject` to a UIKit Sheet.

My expected result is that: I can pass StateObject in `viewDidAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController)`

My actual result is that: I got Xcode warning `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`.

The log

```
NavStackHolder init(id:) 1E1E57BC-1254-4EE3-A745-060B04905AF8
NavStackHolder init(id:) E2DE067C-9407-4D18-8614-69F0F9DC4758
FeatureEViewModel init(id:) 15FA75D8-D91B-42D9-8DCC-CA60F4C50BB3
2023-08-04 11:55:52.214740+0700 WeakUnownedUIKitNavigationExample[9812:256204] [SwiftUI] Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.
NavStackHolder init(id:) C563ED8A-4483-4AE2-8122-050FA5B274C4
```

The example.

```
struct FeatureFView: ViewControllable {
    var holder: NavStackHolder
    
    @ObservedObject var featureEViewModel: FeatureEViewModel
    
    init(holder: NavStackHolder = NavStackHolder(), featureEViewModel: FeatureEViewModel = FeatureEViewModel()) {
        self.holder = holder
        self.featureEViewModel = featureEViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Feature F")
    }
}

final class FeatureEViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let id: UUID
    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct FeatureEView: ViewControllable {
    var holder: NavStackHolder
    
    @StateObject private var featureEViewModel: FeatureEViewModel
    
    init(holder: NavStackHolder = NavStackHolder(), featureEViewModel: FeatureEViewModel = FeatureEViewModel()) {
        self.holder = holder
        self._featureEViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: featureEViewModel)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Feature E")
    }
    
    func viewWillAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        viewController.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    
    func viewDidAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        let view = FeatureFView(featureEViewModel: featureEViewModel)
        
        viewController.navigationController?.present(view.viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The wrapper to enable SwiftUI View - UIKit Navigation.

```
final class NavStackHolder {
    let id: UUID
    
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
        self.id = id
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)")
    }
}

protocol ViewControllable: View {
    var holder: NavStackHolder { get set }
    
    func viewWillAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController)
    func viewDidAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController)
}

extension ViewControllable {
    var viewController: UIViewController {
        let viewController = HostingController(rootView: self)
        self.holder.viewController = viewController
        return viewController
    }
    
    func viewWillAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController) {}
    func viewDidAppear(_ viewController: UIViewController) {}
}

final class HostingController<ContentView>: UIHostingController<ContentView> where ContentView: ViewControllable {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        rootView.viewWillAppear(self)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        rootView.viewDidAppear(self)
    }
}
```

Edit: Half baked solution

Using `@ObservedObject` instead of `@StateObject` in FeatureEView remove the warning. But I believe this a bug not a feature.

Comment: You don’t need a wrapper there, the wrapper doesn’t do anything since it isn’t in a SwiftUI View